# natbib bibliography doesn't compile

Tags: natbib

I'm using natbib and can't get it to run. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
\documentclass[DIV=10,openany, titlepage=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Zeichensatz erweiterter Tex Zeichensatz
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %Silbentrennung nach neuer Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{tikz} %schicke Grafiken
\usepackage{natbib} %Zitierhilfe
\usepackage[symbol, perpage]{footmisc} %nette Fußnoten; symbol für Symbole statt Zahlen
\usepackage{setspace} %einfachere Änderung des Zeilenabstandes
\usepackage{hyperref} %Links im PDF Dokument
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Schicke Kopf und Fußzeile
\usepackage{graphics} %Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{booktabs} %schicke Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{picins} %Grafiken von Text umfließen lassen 
\usepackage{dirtree} %einfach Baumstrukturen setzen
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hfoldsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\citep{Test}

\bibliography{main-tex}

\end{document}
```

blg-file output:

```
I couldn't open database file main-tex.bib
---line 45 of file main-tex.aux
 : \bibdata{main-tex
 :                  }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file main-tex.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Test"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

---

Why can't he create the bib file?

Comment: You need a `\usepackage{natbib}`...

Comment: Sorry, thought this was obvious. But maybe it's indeed a package-problem. I'm going to edit in my packages.

Comment: You should reduce your code to a minimum that produces the problem.  The error message is that it can't find the file `main-tex.bib`.  Do you have such a file?  It should contain your bibtex entries.

Comment: I think I reduced it, I don't know whether other packages could produce that problem. And as I wrote, I don't have a bib-file and I don't know why.

Comment: I thought I could \citet{attributes} and he automatically creates the bib-file and entry. Do I have to fill the bib-file manually for every citation?

Comment: You have to create the `.bib` file yourself.  This is the way you provide the data about the citations.  See http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf for writing the `.bib` file, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131917/15925 for finding entries in the correct format.

Comment: You need to do some BibTeX basics: take a look at the question I've marked this one as a dupe of.