# How to add display text for a URL?

Tags: urls

In markdown, one can

```markdown
[Well-maintained BibTeX Databases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131917/129388)
```

to get [Well-maintained BibTeX Databases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131917/129388)
.
Is there something similar in Latex?

I don't want it to print the whole link, but rather provide a hyperlink that is clickable.
I am not interested in BibTeX, etc stuff.

Comment: Isn't `\href{<URL>}{<text>}` what you're looking for? Of course it requires `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: I've found an almost exact duplicate. Don't delete it, but vote for closing